# How to round multiple numeric columns to 2 digits in sql?

Tags: sql, rounding, digits

Say if I need to round multiple numbers to 2 digits now, but I don't want to repeat using `round(..., 2)` or `format(...)`.

Is there any method to set up the float numbers with 2 digits globally?

Comment: The "global" solution is to change the data type.

Comment: @devlincarnate Do you mean I can't round all numeric columns to 2 digits with a single line in one query?

Comment: You will have to round or convert each field individually.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the column or variable of type numeric(18, 2)

You can also use with the CONVERT function

```
select CONVERT(numeric(18, 2) , 5.54722)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(float_column as decimal(10,2))
from your_table
```